# Can I use any character for the name of my app?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm preparing to publish an app I developed but the name I had in mind is already being used. To solve this I'd like to add a character/symbol (which relates to the name and gameplay) besides the name: ⟡. Is there a problem with doing this? Would this affect my app's visibility on the App Store.

Comment: App names are needed for search. If you use a character then that wouldn't be indexed.  People would find it very difficult to search for your app (assuming Apple allows the character to be used).  Did you look at the App Store guidelines for rules about app naming?

Comment: @fsb If the app name is just two words and the symbol, wouldn't people find it if they just type the words? Would the app be easier to find if there's no symbol at the end?

Comment: I take back what I just said :-).  While I hadn't previously seen special characters in a name, I searched the App Store using *, -, and ( and I saw many apps with those in the name. So it's allowed and devs are doing it. I would never think of searching for a special character in the name unless I knew the app name specifically, so it's something to think about.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [**App Store Review Guidelines**](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), names can be anything so long as they are no more than 30 characters, do not infringe on copyright, and are unique.

So, yes, you can use the ⟡ Unicode character in your app name so long as it follows the guidelines above and on the website.

Comment: But would it make it difficult to find on the App Store?

Comment: @gabe - There's really no way to be sure as that is up to the algorithm in charge of searches on the app store. You are able to change the name of your app, so there's always the option of putting ⟡ in the name, seeing if it works for you, then changing it to the name without the star if it doesn't. Searches are also based on keywords you provide, so the better keywords you provide, the easier it will be to find.